# How to set the password of sqlite into connection using java?

Tags: java, sqlite

My code like this

```
Connection con=DriverManigar.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\data.db);
```

It work fine 
But i encript my sqlite with password using 
DB browser for sqlite

When i open it in any browser of sqlite it ask me the password then when i enter the pass it work fine

So how to enter the password of sqlit to connection in java

I do some thing like this

```
Connection con=DriverManigar.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\data.db ;Password='pass' ");
```

Put it does not work with me

Answer (score 0):

a variant of getConnection() (it's overloaded) is with url as first parameter, username as second, and password as third.

```
getConnection("url","root","1234");
```

Replace root with your username, and 1234 with your password accordingly

Comment: The first code in my post with out username the sqlite just  with password  so what should i put in the username place

Comment: by default it should be root